# Meaning of やな at the end of a sentence

Tags: usage, particles, dialects, sentence-final-particles

In these examples:

> 久しぶりやな

> いい感じやなぁ

I don't understand what "ya" and "na" mean at the end of a sentence

Answer (score 12):

「やな」 is a Kansai affirmative sentence-ender used just like 「**だな**」 in Kanto.

「[久]{ひさ}しぶりやな。」 = "Long time no see, yeah?" or just "Long time no see!"

「いい[感]{かん}じやなぁ。」 = "That's cool.", "That's pretty good.", etc.

Real Kansai people might use ええ, not いい for the second phrase, though.

Comment: ええ isn't really all that common among most young people in my experience unless they're trying to sound extra 関西ish.

Comment: The questioner is not asking how how young people speak.

Answer (score 6):

It means ”だね”, and if I am not mistaken can be heard in the 関西 area.
For example, せやな is the same as そうだね.

So, いい感じやなぁ would be the same as いい感じだね.

Answer (score 4):

### Answer

As other answerers say, you can replace `やな` by `だな`.

```
[雨]{あめ}[降]{ふ}ったみたいやな。 = 雨降ったみたいだな。 (It looks like it rained.)
これは[君]{きみ}のやな？ = これは君のだな？ (It is yours, isn't it?)
```

### A variety of usages / forms

In the same way, you can replace `やね` by `だね`.

`やね (だね)` is a more familiar variation.

```
[雨]{あめ}[降]{ふ}ったみたいやね。 = 雨降ったみたいだね。 (It looks like it rained.)
```

### Exception

To express an agreement for someone's thought, `せやな` and `せやね` are used in some cases. In these sentences, `やな` and `やね` are not replaceable.

```
A: これ[美味]{うま}そうだな。 (It looks like delicious.)
B: せやな。 (It should be.)
```

`せやな` is a correct sentence but `せだな` is not correct.
Let's replace `せ` by `そう`.

```
せやな。 (Correct)
せだな。 (Incorrect)
そうだな。 (Correct)
```

Comment: `せ` is also from Kansai dialect. Example: `せや。` = `そうだ。`