# What does 上 mean here?

Tags: colloquial-language, dialects, conversational, casual

> ずるいずりい、うちのほうが上やったのに上やったのに

Taking 「やった」 as 関西弁の「だった」, does this basically mean:

> [Not fair! I was above you.. I was above you...]

or does わたしは「X」のほうが上です。 have another meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't understand what やな means at the end of a sentence...?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18385/i-dont-understand-what-%e3%82%84%e3%81%aa-means-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

Comment: What 上 means depends on the context. Could you provide what's previously said?

Comment: `does わたしは「X」のほうが上です。 have another meaning?` Here in your example sentence it's **わたしのほうが** （Xより）上です. 「わたしはXのほうが上です」 doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

> > **うち**のほうが上**やった**のに上**やった**のに

Yes, this **やった** is the 関西弁 meaning **だった**. **うち** is also typical in 関西弁 meaning わたし. It appears to be saying "That's not fair. I was the one above (someone)." And repeating the last part showing the feeling of resentment.